# Web crawl using manifoldcf

Tags: web-crawler, manifold, manifoldcf

I'm trying to web crawl data from a specific website using Manifoldcf, but unfortunately, I keep getting 0 results I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I tried creating new Repository Connections as "Generic" and as "WEB" but when I create a job and start it nothing happens and I don't know where can I view the results of the crawling if it ever happened.
[enter image description here][1]

this is my  Repository Connections configuration as "GENERIC" and then I created a JOB that linked the  Repository Connections to my output connection but I don't know if I'm doing something wrong in the configuration itself or I am just not able to see the results of my crawling.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3nla.png

Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the priority of the task to 1 which is the highest, and the crawling started correclty.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).